# Trying to publish build artifact from docker to host system

Tags: docker

I'm trying to publish some artifacts to my host system, but I can't work out how to do it:

`./docker/client/Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /test
RUN echo "hi" > /test/log.txt
VOLUME /test
EXPOSE 3000
```

`./docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  platform-app-frontend:
    image: platform-app-frontend
    build: docker/client
    volumes:
      - ./client/test:/test
    ports:
      - '3100:3100'
```

And I run using:

```
docker-compose up --build platform-app-frontend && ls docker/client/test
```

But there is no file in `docker/client/test`

**EDIT** Comments suggested 2 methods, using `ENTRYPOINT` or using `docker cp`.

I liked `ENTRYPOINT` as it was contiend within the `Dockerfile`,  but alas it was too slow. So I ended up using `docker cp`

Comment: This won’t work this is way. Instead try the Docker cp command.

Comment: ...or if the thing that's building the artifact is a Node process, install Node on your host and use that to build it more directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `./client/test:/test` bind mount is shadowing everything you've put in that folder `/test` during docker build stage.

So, you should do anything like a build within an **ENTRYPOINT** of your image, not at the docker build stage.

Or, as @emix said in the comment, you should just use docker cp command and not a volume.